# returning null for dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following query:

```
select EL.Datetimestart, E.Fullname, VisaExpiryDate, E.EmployeeStatusCode
from EmployeeLog as EL
inner join Employee as E on E.Employeekey = EL.EmployeeKey
where DateTimeStart >= Getdate() -1 and VisaExpiryDate <=GetDate() and E.EmployeeStatusCode <> 'x' 
order by VisaExpiryDate
```

At the moment this will return employees who have a expired visa and are working on that day,

```
VisaExpiryDate - 2017-08-08 00:00:00.000
DateTimeStart - 2017-08-10 08:00:03.090
FullName - Rypsuke
EmployeeStatusCode - C
```

Visa information is checked and inserted into the system and this can take a couple days, so new employees get a 'NULL' as the field is left blank.

**How do i return these nulls to see both who haven't yet had their visas checked and people with expired visas?**

thanks for any help
Nick

Comment: A `NULL` as what field?

Comment: use LEFT JOIN and include VisaExpiryDate IS NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IS NULL

```
select EL.Datetimestart, E.Fullname, VisaExpiryDate, E.EmployeeStatusCode
from EmployeeLog as EL
inner join Employee as E on E.Employeekey = EL.EmployeeKey
where DateTimeStart >= Getdate() -1 and (VisaExpiryDate <=GetDate() OR VisaExpiryDate IS NULL)and E.EmployeeStatusCode <> 'x' 
order by VisaExpiryDate
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, thought it would be simple but that easy... now i feel like a dumb ass :P thanks again <3

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just add a condition to the `where` clause:

```
select EL.Datetimestart, E.Fullname, VisaExpiryDate, E.EmployeeStatusCode
from EmployeeLog EL inner join
     Employee E
     on E.Employeekey = EL.EmployeeKey
where DateTimeStart >= Getdate() - 1 and
      (VisaExpiryDate <= GetDate() or VisaExpiryDate is null) and
      E.EmployeeStatusCode <> 'x' 
order by VisaExpiryDate;
```